# Android file not found exception

Tags: android

What does this imply? Additional details: -The file does exist in the specified location.

The path of file given:

```
mFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/DCIM/x/", "MOV_0022.mp4");
mOutputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(mFile);
mOutputFileUri.toString()

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /file:/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/x/MOV_0022.mp4: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: have you used mnt in the path of the file ?

Comment: Please see the edits.

Comment: did you add the neccessary permissions?

Comment: Yes I have done that. Is that a problem with the file in the beginning?

Comment: are you debugging on device?

Comment: Yes I am debugging in the device

Comment: please turn off USB storage and try again.Make sure USB Debugging is enabled though!@SreekanthKarumanaghat

Comment: @Nezam It doesn't help.

Comment: @SreekanthKarumanaghat it gives same error on emulator with sdcard?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31852/discussion-between-sreekanth-karumanaghat-and-nezam)

Comment: are you sure the file uri is like that? im not sure, but i think it is "file://" or "file:///" instead of "/file:/"

Comment: Yes I am sure that file uri is the same, I am not giving file or thing, it is generated from the Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory.

Comment: @Nezam I am using a Sony Ericsson Tipo.
It has only two modes:-
Media transfer mode.
Mass storage mode.
Which should I choose?

Comment: choose whichever mode which UNMOUNTS your sdcard from the pc..  you are getting the error bcoz your sdcard is unavailable since its mounted to your pc.You can see the removable disk can be opened at pc .. when this happens you will keep getting that error

Answer (score 1):

`getExternalStorageDirectory()`, as stated in the doc, returns a `File` object.

By concatenating to to a String, you `toString` it.

Its String representation is

```
file:///mnt/sdcard
```

This *represent* a File object, but it is not a valid path. It cannot be used that way.

You have to give the constructor a path :

```
mFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "DCIM/x/MOV_0022.mp4");
```

Comment: I hard coded the string as shown below:-
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("file:///mnt/sdcard/DCIM/x/MOV_0022.mp4"));
But this doesn't seem to work. I dont know why.
This gives the same error as above.

Comment: Could this be an error with the SD card connection? I mean wrong connection or something. USB storage options or something.

Comment: it could be that your file does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "DCIM/x/MOV_0022.mp4");
mOutputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(mFile); 
mOutputFileUri.toString();
```

Comment: It doesn't make any difference.

Comment: did you disable using USB storage?It comes down in the notification tray.Click on it and press on turn off or disable

Answer (score 0):

Check if your SDCard is mounted on to PC. You cannot access SDCard simultaneously using 2 applications. If you have mounted it to PC, then unmount it.

Comment: Why is this not a comment??

Comment: Why should this be a comment?

Comment: @Nezam The answer contains one possible reason for OP's problem. I had this issue once, and the steps I said in my answer helped to save it. Also nothing in the page you linked tells me why this answer should be a comment.